# Trying to use import.sql file in spring boot but getting some encoding issue

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am trying to insert some arabic values in database(MySql) but due to some encoding issues it is inserting some what like : Ø§Ù„Ø±ÙŠØ§Ø¶

Also added this in application.properties

' spring.datasource.connectionProperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;autoReconnect=true;useSSL=false '

Thanx in advance

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Issue can solve by using the following maven plugin:

```
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
          <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</argLine>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
```